# Django empty_label for ModelMultipleChoiceField. Multiple values for keyword argument 'empty_label'

Tags: django, forms

I'm trying to put a placeholder in a `Select2` field, by putting `empty_label` in the field. Now i get the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'empty_label'
```

Here is my code:

```
self.fields['work_types'] = ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=WorkTypes.objects.filter(
        white_label_client=logged_in_user.white_label_client,
        deleted=False),
    empty_label='Type',
    required=False)
```

What do i have to change?

Comment: show the rest of your form's code please?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [comments here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/-Msdp36ZLGg), it is a current bug in Django. One of the users said:

> "Looking at it, I would say that this is by design. You shouldn’t use an empty label on a multiple choice field. Perhaps this should be clarified in the docs.
>
> Saying that, if you really want an empty label on a multiple choice field, you could create your own class that initializes empty_label however you want it."

**Further explanation**

> "Well, it is raising an error.  It’s a Python error. Basically, you were passing a keyword argument (empty_label), and the class was passing the same keyword argument called empty_label. Expanded out, this is what was happening:"

```
field = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField( queryset = Imodelclass.objects.all(), empty_label='------------' ) = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset= Imodelclass.objects.all(), empty_label=None, empty_label='------------')
```

> "When you read the error, you see that is actually very clear in this context: You passed two arguments for the same keyword."
>
> "I think it would be wise to mention this in the documentation; perhaps even providing a rationale why ModelMultipleChoiceField should not have an empty label. But if there is no rationale behind it, then the clear solution is to do exactly as you did: remove the empty_label keyword argument from the super call."

Comment: How do you remove empty_label from the super call?

Comment: @DavidAlford one way is to copy the code from the source and use that in your codebase instead of the imported class directly from Django.